# How to replace a 8 channel DIP switch with a chip that controls it digitally

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, transistor-array

There is a 8 channel DIP switch whose state i wanted to change dynamically using a microcontroller. I thought of using an array of mosfets that will do the job. Kindly suggest me a DIP package or a chip (preferably THT) that contains an array of MOSFETS that I can control with the microcontroller without worrying much about current draw and other factors. Any other method to achieve control is also welcome.

I have found a chip ULN2803A that has 8 darlington pairs in it. But the purpose of using ULN2803 is to drive high voltage applications while I want to control and drive low voltage circuits preferably using Nchannel mosfets.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what voltages and currents you are putting through the switch. If you search for "quad analogue switch" or "octal analogue switch" you will come up with likely candidates. It's also possible that what you want could be done with something like a transistor array. It really depends on what the switch is connected to and how.